# How do I type command in pylint

Tags: python

I am trying to use the command "python.linting.pylintArgs" to enable some features in pylint in the visual studio code IDE environment. But I cannot find a way to type the command.

[image: The environement I am using]

I do not know how to type the command in this environment.

This is for an openCV project, running python. In the past, I've tried on Ctrl +Shift+P to type in the command ""python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--reports", "12", "--disable-msg", "I0011"]," it gave me the feedback that there is no such command at all.

Here is my code from readimg.py:

```
img = cv2.imread('g4g.png')  
cv2.imshow('image', img)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The expected result will be that pylint will not warn me of having trouble to find imshow and imread methods in cv2. I know several ways of doing it:

Here's a link to  [the solution](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2426).

But the confusion for me is how do I type the command in VS code:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2"]
```

Comment: That's not a command. It looks like some sort of configuration setting.

Comment: @user2357112 How do I change the configuration setting then?

Comment: @user2357112 Oh I get it. By simply typing crtl + command in the vscode environment. And I can set "pylintArgs."